# CSV values in an array from a custom source

Tags: c#, linq

**Edit**
Solved it people. Used a space in stringSeparators array.
Updated the working code.

I have a csv file which will be used as a template to fill in values.
The place holders or the contents of the file are like so:

[AccountId],[FirstName] [LastName], [Address]

Here's the code to get these place holders:

```
string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { separator," " };

var values = from line in File.ReadAllLines(@"Template.txt")
              select line.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Regards.

Comment: Why not add a `,` - `[AccountId],[FirstName],[LastName],[Address]`?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a second call to `Split`, something like:

```
File.ReadAllLines(@"Template.txt").Select(line =>
{
  var items = line.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
  var names = item[1].Split(' ');
  return new {
     AccountId = items[0],
     FirstName = names[0],
     LastName = names[1],
     Address = items[2]
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't pretty, but something like this would work

```
var values = 
    from line in File.ReadAllLines(@"Template.txt")
    let v = line.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    let name = v[1].Split(' ')
    select new[] {v[0], name[0], name[1], v[2]};
```